# How to change IME options(Return/Go/Done.. keyboard button) in alertDialog edittext?

Tags: android

I have an AlertDialog which has an editText inside, and I want to change the IME options from Return to Done, and call the positiveButton's onClick when the done button is pushed.
I have tried putting

```
        edittext.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

both before and after creating the dialog but it seems it has no effect
also the setOnEditorActionListener isn't being called at all.

the dialog is created from within a function, here is the code:

```
public static void EditTextMessageTwoButtons (Context context, String title, String message,
                                              String negButtonText, String posButtonText,
                                              EditText edittext,
                                              final DialogInterface.OnClickListener posAction) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    if (title != null) {
        builder.setTitle(title);
    }
    if (message != null) {
        builder.setMessage(message);
    }

    builder.setView(edittext);

    builder.setPositiveButton(posButtonText, posAction);

    builder.setNegativeButton(negButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


    final AlertDialog  dialog = builder.show();

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    params.setMargins(Utils.pxFromDp(context, 10), 0, Utils.pxFromDp(context, 10), 0);
    edittext.setLayoutParams(params);

    //doesn't work
    edittext.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

    //not being called at all
    edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
    {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            {
                //is there a way to call the positiveButton onclick directly?
                posAction.onClick(dialog, 1);
                dialog.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little old, but today I ran into the same problem.

Here is how I solved it :

```
public static void showInputAlertDialog(Context context, String title){

    // Create an AlertDialog
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Create EditText to add
    final EditText input = new EditText(context);
    input.setMaxLines(1);
    // Set an IME ACTION
    input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    // And an Action Listener
    input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = true;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // Get the button from the alertDialog you want
                // You don't have getButton function with a AlertDialog.Builder
                Button btn = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                // Call it's onClick
                btn.callOnClick();
                handled=false;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });

    // Add this EditText to the AlertDialog
    alertDialog.setView(input);

    // Set an action for the positive and for he negative buttons
    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do what you want with your new text  // input.getText().toString()
                }
            });
    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Just leave
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    // Set the keyboard visible when you show the AlertDialog
    alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

--Edit--

It's possible to do it with an AlertDialog.Builder.
On .show() function, just save the AlertDialog.

```
private static AlertDialog alertDialog;

public static void showInputAlertDialog(Context context, String title){

     // Create an AlertDialog.Builder
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    builder.setTitle(title);

    // Create EditText to add
    final EditText input = new EditText(context);
    input.setMaxLines(1);
    // Set an IME ACTION
    input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    // And an Action Listener
    input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = true;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // Get the button from the alertDialog you want
                alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
                handled=false;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });

    // Add this EditText to the AlertDialog
    builder.setView(input);

    // Set up the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do what you want with your new text  // input.getText().toString()
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Just leave
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Get the AlertDialog for the builder
    alertDialog = builder.show();
    // Set the keyboard visible when you show the AlertDialog
    alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
}
```